# How to make in TypeScript analogue of Java class literal with generics?

Tags: javascript, java, typescript

I need to make analogue of Java class literal with generics in TypeScript.

This is my Class class:

```
class Class<T> {

    public getName(): string {
        return ...;
    }
}
```

And this is my attempt to create class literal.

```
declare global {

    interface Object {

        class<T extends object>(this: T): Class<T>;//LINE X
    }
}
```

For example, for class `Foo` I want to get literal this way: `Foo.class()`. However, at LINE X I have some mistake because it returns `Class<typeof Foo>` instead of `Class<Foo>`. How to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is meant to be called on classes, you will need a restriction on `T` to ensure that the method only shows up on classes. This can be done using a constructor signature (`new (...a: any[])=> any`)

Since `T` is a class type and you want the instance type you can use the predefined conditional type `InstanceType` to get the instance type from the class type:

```
declare global {
    interface Object {
        class<T extends new (...a: any[])=> any>(this:T): Class<InstanceType<T>>; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you take a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55995840/decorated-field-gives-read-only-error-in-typescript ?