# Decorated field gives read only error in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am learning how to work with decorators and have the following problem. This is my code:

```
function boo(): any {
    return function(target: object, propertyKey: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) {
        console.log("boo");
        return descriptor;
    }
}

class A {

    @boo
    private str: string = null;

    constructor() {
    this.str = "test";
    }

}

let a: A = new A();
```

And this is what I get :

```
TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'str' of object '#<A>'
```

How to fix it?

Comment: With strict null checks `null` is not assignable to `string`. You need to make the type of `str` `string | null` and you need to invoke `boo`, otherwise it should work: https://typescript-play.js.org/?experimentalDecorators=true#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAIznAFASgFyIIZgCeiA3gFCKWIBOAplCNUqJLAulHtQOb25zIAVrWgAaRAAdqcCbWpRCAaVqFcAZyjUYYbuIAmtNRC0SocargAK02fMIARQ8ZinzmUhSpeICNXAA2tAB0-nDc6ABEqHARmADcnl6UdAxMiAZGJmbUCV4AvmQFZBD+eGpqiACCHomIAALRWLVSMABueFC0iBoW3Zra3AA+iGAg-v6IALwjY-4JtT5gPSDQ5lgeXlAAFjBqQT1TiBGdGhG5VEVFgVD4uNXTYLQA7lVYcUA

Comment: It depends on how you define the decorator, what you are defining above is a decorator factory if `boo` would just be the inner function you would not need to invoke it, that is the actual decorator function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With strict null checks null is not assignable to `string`. You need to make the type of `str` `string | null`.

The other issue is that you need to invoke `boo`. `boo` is technically a decorator factory. The decorator itself is the function with the signature `(target: object, propertyKey: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) => PropertyDescriptor`.

```
function boo(): any {
    return function(target: object, propertyKey: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) {
        console.log("boo");
        return descriptor;
    }
}

class A {

    @boo()
    private str: string| null = null;

    constructor() {
        this.str = "test";
    }

}

let a: A = new A();
```

You need to use a decorator factory if you need to pass in extra parameters to the decorator. Ex:

```
function boo(otherInfo: string): any {
    return function (target: object, propertyKey: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) {
        console.log("boo " + otherInfo);
        return descriptor;
    }
}

class A {

    @boo("Other info")
    private str: string | null = null;

    constructor() {
        this.str = "test";
    }

}
```

In this case you don't really need to use a decorator factory, this would work as well:

```
function boo(target: object, propertyKey: string) {
    console.log("boo");
}

class A {

    @boo
    private str: string | null = null;

    constructor() {
        this.str = "test";
    }

}
```

Although the above works, I would generally still use a decorator factory, easier to add parameters later and makes things consistent.

Comment: And if you have a free minute, could you take a look at this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55994603/how-to-get-class-field-type-using-reflect-only-using-constructor ?

Comment: @Jim2018 always happy to help, also happy for the rep points :)

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will test your answer. Could you explain when to use decorator and when to use decorator factory?

Comment: @Jim2018 added explanation of that .

Comment: Thank you! Is descriptor passed only to the nested function of decorator factory?

Comment: @Jim2018 that is actually a difference between property and field decorators, fields don't have a descriptor